# ExtJS Paging with Combo box

Tags: javascript, extjs, combobox

Created a combo box with ExtJS framework. But Pagination is not working. could you please help on this?

```
var store =   new Ext.data.ArrayStore({
    fields: ['id'],
    pageSize:1,
    data  : [
      ['15'],       ['25'],       ['225'],       ['325'],       ['525'],       ['625'],       ['125'],       ['8725'],       ['825'],       ['1825'],       ['3825'],       ['4825'],       ['67825'],       ['82725'],       ['84725'],       ['86725'],       ['87525'],       ['87625'],       ['872665'],       ['235'],       ['235'],       ['225'],       ['245'],       ['550']
    ]
  });
var combo = new Ext.form.ComboBox({
  name : 'perpage',
  width: 40,
  mode : 'remote',
  value: '1',
  store:       store, //the store you use in your grid

  pageSize:true,
  listWidth     : 1,
  width         : 600,
  triggerAction : 'all',
  displayField  : 'id',
  valueField    : 'id',
  forceSelection: true
});


var window = Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
    width: 650,
    height: 100,
    items: [combo]
}).show();
```

All the Data i.e. 24 records are shown in each page. [image]

As shown in the image each page showing all 24 records. Expectation is each page with 1 record.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The combobox always shows all data that is in the store. Normally, the store does not hold all data from the server when you use paging. The proxy thus manages the data.

Please check what happens if you use a MemoryProxy with enablePaging and data:

```
var store =   new Ext.data.ArrayStore({
    fields: ['id'],
    pageSize:1,
    proxy: {
        type:'memory'
        enablePaging:true,
        data  : [
            ['15'],       ['25'],       ['225'],       ['325'],       ['525'],       ['625'],       ['125'],       ['8725'],       ['825'],       ['1825'],       ['3825'],       ['4825'],       ['67825'],       ['82725'],       ['84725'],       ['86725'],       ['87525'],       ['87625'],       ['872665'],       ['235'],       ['235'],       ['225'],       ['245'],       ['550']
        ]
    }
});
```